# Google Sheets Logger values into rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, urlfetch

I am pulling data from a `.csv` file generated after a URL request using `UrlFetchApp.fetch` and storing the data using the logger.

Is there a way to write each row of fetched data from the logger into separate rows in a spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this quite a while ago.  It's how I import data from website visitor logs.  To review them. I don't use commas because you find them in the data too often.  I use 3 tildes '~~~' instead and the lines are separated with a line feed '\n'.
But I basically split the lines and then fields on each line into array and feed them into the sheets one line at a time and usually I deal with 20 or 30 files about 100K or less. And I find that it loads the files very quickly.

```
function importData1(myFolderID,myFolderName,myFileName) {
  var myFolderID = typeof(myFolderID) !== 'undefined' ? myFolderID : 'FolderID';
  var myFileName = typeof(myFileName) !== 'undefined' ? myFileName : '';
  if(myFileName && myFolderID)
  {
    var fi = DriveApp.getFolderById(myFolderID).getFilesByName(myFileName); // Selected IPLogYYMMDD.txt file
    var ssid = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId();
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssid); 
    if (fi.hasNext() ) // proceed if file exists in the IPlogs folder
    { 
      var file = fi.next();
      var data = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
      var lines = data.split('\n');
      var newsheet = ss.insertSheet(myFolderName + '/' + myFileName); 
      var j=0;
      for (var i=0; i<lines.length; i++ ) 
      {
        var fields = lines[i].split('~~~');
          if(fields.length>=8)//There's supposed to be 8 or 9 fields
        {
          Logger.log('i=' + i + 'fields.length=' + fields.length);
          newsheet.getRange(j+1, 1, 1,fields.length).setValues([fields]);
          j=j+1;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  else
  {
    displayStatus('Error Importing Data','Either Folder or File not found in importData1');
  }
```

Most of the variables are easy to figure out.  You'll probably be able to adapt it to what you need.  And probably there will be several optional answers for you to chose from.

Comment: Why not use `parseCsv(csv_string[, delimiter])` from the Utilities service? Then you can just blat the resulting 2D array into your sheet.

Comment: Good idea. Didn't know about that. I'll try it next time.

Comment: Works great! Thank you